# htaccess rewrite appending directory structure to url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to map user selected sub domains to user directories on the web folder like so:

user1 has user1.domain.com which points to /domains/user1

if accessing a subdirectory in the user's folder with a trailing slash, it works fine. without a trailing slash, it'll append the entire structure.

works fine -> user1.domain.com/folder1/
does not work -> user1.domain.com/folder1

when accessing user1.domain.com/folder1, it'll redirect the user to user1.domain.com/domains/user1/folder1

accessing user1.domain.com/folder1/ (note the trailing slash) it works fine.

when two directories deep, it works as expected
user1.domain.com/folder1/folder2 and user1.domain.com/folder1/folder2/ work without issue.

this is the existing htaccess file

```
#enable user subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.domain\.com$[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domains/(.*?)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /domains/%1/$1/
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you manually enter `user1.domain.com/domains/user1/folder1/` in address bar?

Comment: @DusanBajic should get a 404 if done right.

Comment: Yes, but at the moment, with the current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
# enable user subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!domains(?:$|/)).* domains/%1/$0 [L]
```

Don't add another trailing slash otherwise you'll end up with doubles, internally.